# Разработать Java-приложение с графическим интерфейсом пользователя

Tags: java

Разработать Java-приложение с графическим интерфейсом пользователя.
Кнопка "Открыть" вызывает диалог открытия файлов, содержимое выбранного пользователем файла считывается в заданную структуру данных (у каждого свой вариант).
При нажатии на кнопку "Показать" содержимое структуры данных отображается в многострочном поле ввода (объект класса JTextArea)/ Для классов, реализующих интерфейс Map, надо выводить и ключ, и значение.
Кнопка "Выход" служит для закрытия приложения.
Для следующих заданий - модификация пользовательского интерфейса: в интерфейс добавить однострочное текстовое поле ввода (объект класса JTextField), куда пользователь сможет ввести параметр (строку, число и т.д.)
ArrayList, вывести первые N строк (N задается пользователем)
Подскажите пожалуйста, как выполнить данный вывод?

```java
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jTextArea1.setText("");
        
   int N=0;
        if(Objects.equals(jTextField1.getText(), ""))
            N = 0;
        else
            N = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
             
            for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                jTextArea1.append(""+list.get(N)+"\n");
            
            }
        }
```

Comment: какой данный вывод?

Comment: Привет, уточни пожалуйста, что в итоге должно быть? Просто на данный момент я понял, что необходимо добавить компонент JTextField. 
Но не понял, что нужно сделать с ArrayList.

Comment: Открывается файл,затем в строку JTextField вводится число N,а в кнопке jButton3ActionPerformed 
мы должны вывести все строки до введенного числа N
К примеру в файле 100 строк,мы вводим N=50 и по кнопке должно вывезти 49 строк (с 1 по 49 включительно)

Comment: То есть мы читаем файл, заполняем массив данными с файла и выводим их в консоль? У вас вопрос в том как прочитать файл?

Comment: у меня вопрос,как вывезти строки из файла
с 1 по N
,а выводим мы их в окно  JTextArea
насколько я понимаю через  JTextArea.append

Comment: jTextArea1.append(""+list.get(N)+"\n"); нужно N заменить на i

Comment: Спасибо огромное,все заработало,извините,что так криво объяснил свою проблему

Comment: Рад был помочь)

Answer (score 0):

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

`jTextArea1.append(""+list.get(N)+"\n");`

нужно N заменить на i